# Convert hex to integer value from measurement data of CO2 sensor in C

Tags: hex, stm32, sensors, uart

I'm reading hex values from a CO2 sensor that communication through UART (https://www.co2meter.com/products/explorir-10-co2-smart-led-sensor?variant=20504457773174), and I would like to convert hex value in ppm value or percentage, since CO2 value are measured in this way. I'm using STM32 microcontroller and this is my C code:

```
  ret_uart = HAL_UART_Receive(&huart3, (uint8_t *)RdBuffer, BUFFSIZE, 2000);
  if (ret_uart != HAL_OK){
      strcpy((char*)buf_uart, "Error Rx\r\n");
  }
  else{
      ret_uart = HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3, (uint8_t *)RdBuffer, BUFFSIZE, 2000);
      if (ret_uart != HAL_OK){
          strcpy((char*)buf_uart, "Error Tx\r\n");
      }
      else{
          return 1;
      }
  }
```

For instance the masured value is 0x20, but how I can convert into an integer value?

Since I got mesurement inside an office, I expect a CO2 concentration of around 400pm which is equal to 0.04%, which may depends from the sea level.

Comment: How do you get that `0x20` value? Is that the whole received message (`char` buffer`) an integer ?

Comment: "*For instance the masured value is 0x20, ...*" -- Not likely. You're probably misinterpreting the response. According to the manual, the command/response dialog is in lines of ASCII text. Seems like you're treating a byte of text as its binary value. You probably have not yet realized that a byte has a binary value that is typically reported using hexadecimal representation, and can be interpreted/used as a numeric value, or an encoded character, or part of a CPU instruction, or part of a multi-byte integer or floating-point number.